# How does WebPageHttpModule happen to be registered after my modules?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, ihttpmodule

In my web.config `<system.webServer>` section I add my custom module:

```
<modules>
    <add name="MyCustomModule" type="MyAssembly.MyCustomModule, MyAssembly" />
</modules>
```

and then in my HTTP handler I iterate over the modules list:

```
var allModules = HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.Modules;
for( int i = 0; i < allModules.Count; i++ ) {
    Trace(allModules.GetKey(i));
}
```

and I get this list:

```
__ASP_IntegratedDynamicModule_Shim
OutputCache
Session
FormsAuthentication
DefaultAuthentication
RoleManager
AnonymousIdentification
Profile
UrlMappingsModule
ServiceModel-4.0
UrlRoutingModule-4.0
ScriptModule-4.0
MyCustomModule <<<<<<<<<<<<<My Module
__DynamicModule_System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpModule, System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35_2d022434-c92d-4088-bfa6-3478c4fc129d
```

Clearly my module is registered after all built-in modules except that WebPageHttpModule is registered after it.

How does that happen? How could I possibly ensure that my own module gets registered last?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WebPageHttpModule` module is registered using [the `RegisterModule` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.infrastructure.dynamicmodulehelper.dynamicmoduleutility.registermodule%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) from [the `Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper.DynamicModuleUtility` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.infrastructure.dynamicmodulehelper.dynamicmoduleutility_methods%28v=vs.111%29.aspx). Any module registered with this method will be registered after modules defined in the config file.

You could try [registering your own module using this method](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/02/register-your-http-modules-at-runtime.html). However, there's no way to guarantee that your module will be registered last. In most cases, the order shouldn't matter.